# Community user verification email

Tags: customer-community, lightning-community, customer-portal, community-builder, self-registration

I am setting a self-registration module for our community and once the user signups I want the user to get an email to verify themselves before the users get created in the community. But currently, I am seeing that I am only getting a welcome email with a link to change the password. When I check in our org the members are created. Would like to understand how do I set up this verification process in which only once the user verifies the email the community user is created.

Also with the welcome email on clicking the link and changing the password, the user does not land on the community home page, instead, it lands on .force.com/home2/apex/CommunitiesLanding, would like to understand how do I change this behavior?

[image]

Comment: You may want to look into the passwordless login or Doscovery login for community

Comment: Thanks, Manjit that's helpful. But I still get emails with reset password links, once the user is set up in the org.  I would like to know we could send verification mail to users only after which the user record is created in Salesforce.